# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/json/JsonValue

Tags: java

when I try to use ContainerFactory in my project，I got error message "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/json/JsonValue"。But I already add dependency "jakarta.json-api 2.0.1 version" in my pom.xml; However when I use the lower version "jakarta.json-api 1.1.6" ,it work well.
My question is that this "javax/json/JsonValue" doesn't exist in 2.0.1 version but in 1.1.6 version?

I am try to figure out that "javax/json/JsonValue" exist in "jakarta.json-api 2.0.1 version" or not

Comment: Please share the dependency in the pom. Check if there is a conflicting version from a transitive dependency.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.